# Error message when running sDNA license manager, Windows 10

Tags: qgis, sdna

I want to install sDNA for QGIS (Windows 10, QGIS 3) and when I try to run the license manager, I get this error message (I'm running both as admin)

[image: Error message sDNA license manager]

I've tried to click continue, but after I copy and paste my license in the field and click on "Get Challenge URL", the same message pops up again. I clicked on "continue" again, but the status information field just says "Please wait" and nothing happens.  Reinstall didn't help and using different versions of sDNA (3.4.6 and 3.4.7) didn't help either (both times the same problem)

Do you maybe know what went wrong and what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Windows 10 is not officially supported. Have you tried running in compatibility mode for windows 7 - also running as administrator?

Comment: the "side by side" often means having 32 and 64 bit versions of the same software/library. "vs2008" refers to Visual Studio 2008, and if you don't have it (most people don't), you would want to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable", both 32 and 64 bits versions. (google it, it's free from Microsoft website). (PS: the 32 bits version is also known as x86)

Answer (score 0):

sDNA has not been ported to QGIS 3.x.x SO if you are trying to install sDNA with QGIS 3.x.x it won't work.